# Find text within brackets in PHP

Tags: php

I am passing a value from one page to another page like

date + start time + end time

and it would be be in format 24th of August 2014 Sun02:00am12:00pm

and I am using something like `substr($_POST['datetimevalue'], 0, -11);` to de-concatenate the values but I am getting issue with date size as sometimes size on month may change to less or more.

I can switch to the format start time + end time + date but its still a bad idea.

I wish to change the format to date + {start time} + [end time] so that it will be like 24th of August 2014 Sun{02:00am}[12:00pm]

How can I find the value within `{ }` and value within `[ ]`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```
$value = '24th of August 2014 Sun{02:00am}[12:00pm]';
preg_match('/(.+){(.+)}\[(.+)\]/', $value, $matches);;
list( , $date, $start, $end ) = $matches;
```

**[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9148489ccf25c4d9cb70365bc8e9096cbc4c8f43)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will work for you.

```
function findByDelimiters ($string, $start, $end) {

    $initial_pos = strpos($string, $start);

    if ($initial_pos !== false) {

        $substr = substr($string, $initial_pos + strlen($start));

        $final_pos = strpos($substr, $end);

        if ($final_pos !== false) {
            return trim(substr($substr, 0, $final_pos));
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Delimiter opened, but not closed (Input: ' . $string . ', open: ' . $start . ', expected close: ' . $end);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example of use:

```
findByDelimiters ('August 2014 Sun{02:00am}[12:00pm]', '{', '}') // Prints: 02:00am
findByDelimiters ('August 2014 Sun{02:00am}[12:00pm]', '[', ']') // Prints: 12:00pm
```